# connect: Network unreachable - Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, networking, netplan

sorry for the possibly dumb question but I just can't find a solution specific to my issue. I'm a linux newbie trying to manage a VPS server and I'm in trouble. I just restarted my VPS and now my machine can’t reach the network. Everything was working before that.

Could someone PLEASE help me?

I'm running some docker containers but I'm not able to use internet anywhere.
I'm also using `netplan` instead of `ifupdown`

`ifconfig` results:

```
br-0c7683224a70: flags=4163<UP, BROADCAST, RUNNING, MULTICAST› mtu 1500
  inet 172.18.0.1 netmask 255.255.0.0 broadcast 172.18.255.255
  inet6 fe80::42:60ff :fee3:3564 pref ixlen 64 scope id 0x20<1 ink>
  ether 02:42:60:e3:35:64 txqueuelen 0 (Ethernet)
  RX packets 34 bytes 2016 (2.0 KB)
  R errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0
  TX packets 51 bytes 4534 (4.5 KB)
  TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0

docker0: flags=4163<UP, BROADCAST, RUNNING, MULTICAST› mtu 1500
  inet 172.17.0.1 netmask 255.255.0.0 broadcast 172.17.255.255
  inet6 fe80::42:e2ff :fe3a:6cd2 pref ixlen 64 scope id 0x20<1 ink>
  ether 02:42:e2:3a:6c:d2 txqueuelen 0 (Ethernet)
  R packets 20 bytes 1600 (1.6 KB)
  R errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0
  TX packets 35 bytes 3384 (3.3 KB)
  TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0

enp6s0: flags=4163<UP, BROADCAST, RUNNING, MULTICAST› mtu 1450
  inet6 fe80::5800:2ff :fe9a:fdb3 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x20<1 ink>
  ether 5a :00:02:9a :fd:b3 txqueuelen 1000 (Ethernet)
  RX packets 4 bytes 520 (520.0 B)
  RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0
  TX packets 37 bytes 7082 (7.0 KB)
  TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP , LOOPBACK, RUNNING> mtu 65536
  inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 255.0.0.0
  inet6 ::1 pref ixlen 128 scoped 0x10<host>
  loop txqueuelen 1000 (Local Loopback)
  RX packets 15154 bytes 1578872 (1.5 MB)
  R errors 0 dropped overruns 0 frame 0
  TX packets 15154 bytes 1578872 (1.5 MB)
  TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0

veth14db567: flags=4163<UP , BROADCAST, RUNNING, MULTICAST› mtu 1500
  inet6 fe80::d494:1bff :feaa:943b pref ixlen 64 scope id 0x20<1 ink›
  ether d6:94:1b: aa:94:3b txqueuelen 0 (Ethernet)
  R packets 10 bytes 940 (940.0 B)
  R errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0
  TX packets 26 bytes 2355 (2.3 KB)
  TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0

veth375de13: flags=4163<UP, BROADCAST, RUNNING, MULTICAST› mtu 1500
  inet6 fe80: : b853:27ff :fe5c: 413 pref ixlen 64 scopeid 0x20<1 ink›
  ether ba:53:27:5c:04:13 txqueuelen 0 (Ethernet)
  RX packets 25 bytes 15478 (15.4 KB)
  RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0
  TX packets 52 bytes 4831 (4.8 KB)
  TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0

vethc49e94d: flags=4163<UP , BROADCAST, RUNNING, MULTICAST> mtu 1500
  inet6 fe80::e8ad:b6ff: fead:10f9 pref ixlen 64 scopeid 0x20<1 ink>
  ether ea:ad: b6: ad:10:f9 txqueuelen 0 (Ethernet)
  R packets 49 bytes 4597 (4.5 KB)
  R errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0
  TX packets 56 bytes 18118 (18.1 KB)
  TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0

vethfOeef78: flags=4163<UP , BROADCAST, RUNNING, MULTICAST> mtu 1500
  inet6 fe80::f020:51ff: fe8a: 7e2c pref ixlen 64 scopeid 0x20<1 ink›
  ether f2:20:51:8a:7e:2c txqueuelen 0 (Ethernet)
  R packets 0 bytes 0 (0.0 B)
  RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0
  TX packets 18 bytes 1300 (1.3 KB)
  TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0
```

Results of `route`:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination   Gateway   Genmask       Flags   Metric   Ref   Use   Iface
172.17.0.0    0.0.0.0   255.255.0.0   U       0        0     0     docker0
172.18.0.0    0.0.0.0   255.255.0.0   U       0        0     0     br-Oc7683224a70
```

I have literally NO idea what is happening

Comment: Edit your question and include the steps you took that brought you into this situation. Your primary interface (`enp6s0`) only has a link-local adress IPv6 adress. Also, consider using `ip` instead of `ifconfig`.

Comment: I actually didn’t do anything. I just restarted the server (which was working before) and I got that :(

Comment: You should try your provider management interface and get your IP address. My server is given ks3001154.kimsufi.com. I can resolves its address and put it in `/etc/network/interfaces`. You should also send a ticket to your provider in order to get a default route. Here, you have none ! No one here can guess which default route you should have. (Provider dependant… and worse, it depends on the rack inside which your server is).

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that there was no default route. I know my IP (104.207.132.185) but I don’t know how to add the default route. I just opened a ticket at vultr tho.

Comment: If you have made no changes, I would suggest starting the server in emergency mode and seeing if you have connectivity. It is possible that you may have made changes and they did not take effect until you rebooted and are now conflicting.